# How to aggregate Objects in Seq properly?

Tags: scala

My fonction returns Objects(Seq[Object(1, 2), Object(1, 2)]).
And my purpose is to aggregate the content of these two objects in one object like this: Objects(Object(2, 4)). I get the first result that way:

```
 val results = ids.map { id =>
      for {
        something       <- myDAO.selectSomething(id)
        somethingf       <- myDAO.selectSomethingElse(id)
      } yield {
        MyObject(
          something,
          somethingf
        )
      }
 }

 Future.sequence(results).map(Objects(_))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `foldLeft` like so

```
case class MyObject(a: Int, b: Int)
val l = List(MyObject(1,2), MyObject(1,2))
l.foldLeft(MyObject(0,0)) { (acc, o) => MyObject(acc.a + o.a, acc.b + o.b) }
```

or shorter `reduce`

```
l.reduce { (acc, o) => MyObject(acc.a + o.a, acc.b + o.b) }
```

or define `MyObject` addition as infix operator

```
implicit class MyObjectAddition(x: MyObject) {
  def + (y: MyObject): MyObject = MyObject(x.a + y.a, x.b + y.b)
}
```

and then simply `reduce` with

```
l.reduce(_ + _)
```

or define [`Semigroup`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/semigroup.html) for `MyObject`

```
import cats.Semigroup
implicit val intAdditionSemigroup: Semigroup[MyObject] =
  (x: MyObject, y: MyObject) => MyObject(x.a + y.a, x.b + y.b)
```

and reduce with

```
import cats.syntax.semigroup._
l.reduce(_ |+| _)
```

All options output

```
res0: MyObject = MyObject(2,4)
```